# Tool tip not showing for those label who's data overlapped on each other in chart.js

Tags: chart.js, angular7, radar-chart

I have created spidar (radar) chart by using chart.js here- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ytsbxn.
When we have  data = [100,100,100,200] like this, then all three label's node get overlap on each other so in this case tooltip showing for only one label as you can see in demo.

[image: Spidar chart]

how can i solved this tooltip issue for overlapped nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define [`tooltips.mode: 'point'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#point) and then define [`tooltips.callbacks`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) funtions for `title` and `label` in order to obtain meaningful data displayed in the tooltips.

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'point',
  callbacks: {
    title: () => 'DataCombination',
    label: (tooltipItem, data) => data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ': ' + data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index]
  }
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x5e54p)